# Using generics in method: exception in compilation: complaining about type :cannont convert to

Tags: java, generics

The code below throws a exception in "return list;"  with typemismatch . Its suposed to not to.

```
public class Teste {

    public <S extends TestPai> S getList(){
        TestPai list = new TesteFilho();
        return  list;
    }
}

class TesteFilho implements TestPai{

}

interface TestPai{

}
```

I found a soluction to it, puting it like this

```
public class Teste {
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <S extends TestPai> S getList(){
        TestPai list = new TesteFilho();
        return  (S)list;
    }
}

class TesteFilho implements TestPai{

}

interface TestPai{

}
```

But it sounds weird , since i have other codes that where compiled before that arent performing like that.
- Im using eclipse IDE  in a windows machine with jre1.7.0_51 as execution environment.

Can somebody help to make it works as is expected (in the first code).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you could tell us more about what you are trying to do. The code example is not how generics are used.

Comment: looking just to something like this code:

Comment: looking just to something like this code:

   public <S extends FatherOfAll> S getList(){
        FatherOfAll list = new SonA();
        return  list;
    }

Supose that its a command (thinking into the gang of 4 pattern), i want to make sure that im returning a subclass of something, but i can create anything i want to, that matches the subclass.

the point i raised, is , why java is complaining about it in compiling time, the first code should be compiled without errors....

Comment: @Radiodef , the point of it, for me is that the signature of the method `<S extends FatherOfAll> S  getList()` should match with the code, since the class is a subclass of the FatherOfAll.

Answer (score 1):

All the types are fixed! You're not using the type parameter at all. So the simplest way is just

```
public TestPai getList(){
    TestPai list = new TesteFilho();
    return  list;
}
```

Comment: This code is a abstraction of the real one, since its from the place where i work. The original code really does what im saying above and the reason (at least how it looks like) is because they want to return something that implements the interface, and it could have subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why generics are needed here.  You are attempting to return any kind of `TestPai`, but that would be covered by returning the actual concrete type.

If any kind of `TestPai` can be returned, then this will do:

```
public TestPai getList(){
```

If only an implementing class `TesteFilho` can be returned, then return that implementing class:

```
public TesteFilho getList(){
```

(That means that `list` has to be a `TesteFilho` too.)

Comment: This code is a abstraction of the real one, since its from the place where i work. The original code really does what im saying above and the reason (at least how it looks like) is because they want to return something that implements the interface, and it could have subclasses..